# How can I call JSON object data in a global string outside getJson?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

## UPDATED

This is my structure:

**FILE.json**

```
{
    "Page": [
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "IsActive":true,
            "PageName":"crosstownrunning",
            "PageURL":"crosstownrunning"
        }    
    ]
}
```

**FILE.js**

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

// VARS
var PageTemplate;

// GET JSON
jQuery.getJSON("FILE.json", function (x) {
    // alert(x.Page[0].PageName);  << This works
    PageTemplate = x.Page[0];
});

alert (PageTemplate.PageName);
alert (PageTemplate.PageURL);
// Can I make PageTemplate.anything bring up my JSON data outside getJSON function?

});
```

How can I call the `x` outside the function?

Comment: Turn on the debugger and check that the request for the file is sent. Also check that your file is in the same path as your js file as you have not specified a complete URI

Comment: What are you expecting as result if more than one page? Anyway in your code `Page` is undefined, x is the object. Question could be, why Page is an array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery.getJSON("FILE.json", function (x) {
    alert(x.Page[0].PageName);
});
```

Comment: But I cannot call the strings outside the function

Comment: You need save "x" in local variable in outside;

Comment: Not, sorry, is asynchronous query. You can't use outside_X ! You need write all code in transmitted function. Code jQuery.getJSON launch ajax query, and run to next operation.  When http get your FILE.json, he launch function (x){ ... } from datas in "x"

Comment: Example of having this outside any function. I just want it in the jQuery document.ready function

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the callback function since `jQuery.getJSON` function is asynchronous.

```
jQuery.getJSON("FILE.json", function(x) {
    $('.emptyBox').append(x.Page[0].PageURL);
});
```

Comment: `Page.PageURL` still isn't correct, since `Page` is an array of objects, not an object itself.

Comment: What he is saying is that PageTemplate won't contain any data until the call completes, and in addition will probably be something like PageTemplate.Page[0].PageURL

Comment: I want to be able to call variables inside the JSON file anywhere in my jQuery file .... not just in this function

Comment: @vogomatix I know what he's saying, that doesn't make the code he originally had correct.

Comment: @vogomatix to use it anywhere in your file store it in the callback function: `PageTemplate = x.Page[0];`